# Container parameter not available/injected in Symfony 5 service when runnig PHPUnit tests

Tags: symfony, phpunit

While creating some (functional) PHPUnit tests for my Symfony 5 project, I ran into the problem, that container parameters are not properly injected into services during the tests:

For example the following parameters are available an used in the project:

```
// config/packages/some_bundle.yaml
some_bundle:
    api:
        key: 'abc'     // default value is null
        mode: 'live'   // default value is 'sandbox'


// SomeBundle/config/services.yaml
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true
        autoconfigure: true

    bind:
        $apiMode: '%some_bundle.api.mode%'
        $apiKey: '%some_bundle.api.key%'


// SomeBundle/src/Service/ApiService.php
class ApiService {
    public function __construct($apiMode, $apiKey) {
        // log mode and key ...
    }
}


// Checking that parameters are available
$ php bin/console debug:container --parameters --env=test

Symfony Container Parameters
============================

------------------------------------------- 
Parameter               Value                                                                                 
-------------------------------------------
...
some_bundle.api.key     abc
some_bundle.api.mode    live
```

**The problem:**

I would assume that when using these parameters during tests, that their values are `abc` and `live`. However, logging shows, that the `ApiService` is created with the default values `null` and `sandbox` instead when running the tests.

The testCase extends `KernelTestCase` and the kernel is booted. Getting the parameter directly from the test container also shows the wrong value:

```
// Within the test case
$mode = self::getContainer()->getParameter('some_bundle.api.mode');
$this->assertEquals($mode, 'live', 'error');

// test output
Failed asserting that two strings are equal.
--- Expected
+++ Actual
@@ @@
-'live'
+'sandbox'
```

When using the project directly in browser, everything is fine.

The `dev`, `prod` and `test` environment all use the same config files, there a no special `env.test` files.

The `phpunit.xml.dist` file is setup to use the `test` environment, but using other environments here does not make any difference.

```
<phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" ...>
    <php>
        <server name="APP_ENV" value="test" force="true" />
        ...
```

How to solve this? Are container parameters skipped completly when running tests and only default values can be used? Or is there anything wrong with my config?

Comment: env.local variables are not loaded in tests. You will have to create a env.test or env.test.local file with your test config or add the vars to the phpunit.xml.dist

Comment: I am not sure if this is relevant, since this is about container parameters, not environment variables. What would I have to include in `env.test` to make autowire correctly inject the container parameter `some_bundle.api.mode`? As described all container parameters are shown with their correct test values when calling `php bin/console debug:container --parameters --env=test` in terminal, but with their default values when being accessed during the test (e.g. using `self::getContainer()->getParameter('some_bundle.api.mode')`). How can this be fixed using the `.env.xxx` files?

Comment: Sorry didn't read the entire issue in depth. Have you registered the bundle correctly so using all environments? ```['all' => true]```

Comment: Also have you booted the kernel?

Comment: @James Yes, the kernel is booted (as described in the question) and the bundle is also registered correctly using `['all' => true]` in the `bundles.php`

Comment: Too much code to put in a comment so just added it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I can't really see anything wrong with the way you have done it and would have thought it would work, although I wouldn't have injected the parameters like that. In my bundle in the DependencyInjection folder I would pass the params in the extension file instead of binding them in the services.yaml.

```
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
    {
        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__ . '/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yaml');
        
        $definition = $container->getDefinition('SomeBundle/src/Service/ApiService');
        $definition->addArgument($configs['api']['mode']);
        $definition->addArgument($configs['api']['key']);
    }
```